# ROS and gazebo for tum_simulator

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wanted to know what is the minimum version of ROS with which tum_simulator ( for A.R. drone ) can work with ?
The website mentions ROS fuerte but there are videos on youtube that claim to use ROS-indigo with tum_simulator.

I have seen [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/251601/is-there-a-simulator-for-ardrone-in-ros-kinetic/) question and it suggests to use  [this github package](https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator)  for ROS-kinetic.
However, it is unclear whether this github source has all functionalities as tum_simulator has.

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS-kinetic.

Could someone kindly help ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281459/ros-and-gazebo-for-tum_simulator/) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the top of the package's [README](https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator/blob/master/README.md), it says

> **tum_simulator ported to Kinetic.**
>
> Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.1, ROS Kinetic and using Gazebo 7.

so presumably it will work on Ubuntu 16.04.1 with ROS Kinetic and Gazebo 7. I know that people are using it as a replacement (update) for the `tum_simulator` package.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-02-01**:
Does it contain all the functionalities then ? ( Since it is not on the official ROS wiki page for tum_simulator )

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-01**:
I can only go off of what the README says. You can ask the maintainer.